# Grouping javascript method functionality into a javascript "class"

Tags: javascript, ajax, class

Yes, I understand that JavaScript doesn't have "classes" per se, so I'll just throw that out there up front and move on.

I have an app that has a left sidebar that lists a bunch of tags.  I'm manipulating these tags via JavaScript and AJAX to add, remove, and update the tags.

When I currently manipulate the tags, it goes something to the effect of (note this code is a dumbed-down version of what I'm doing, but conveys the point; also, I'm using the jQuery library):

```
# HTML page...
<div id="tags">
  <div class="tag" id="tag_1">tag text</div>
  <div class="tag" id="tag_2">tag text</div>
  <div class="tag" id="tag_3">tag text</div>
  ...
</div>

# Javascript to create new tag
$("#tags").append("<div class='tag' id='tag_15'>text</div>")

# update a tag
$("#tag_10").replace("<div class='tag' id='tag_10'>updated tag</div>")

# remove a tag
$("#tag_10").remove()
```

As a side note, I'm using the Rails framework and some of the JS is created on the server via js.erb files and sent back to the client to evaluate.  I'm aware of some concerns with servers generating JS, but it's OK in this situation.

So I decided that I should group this functionality into a JavaScript "class" that controls the tags on my page.

The issue is that I have a single tags sidebar, so I don't need multiple Tag objects...I just need a bunch of named methods that allow me to manipulate the tags on my page in an orderly fashion.

I would like to be able to do things like:

```
Tag.append({ text: "tag text", id: <id of tag> }) => the append functionality above
Tag.update(<id to update>, { <hash of options> })
Tag.remove(<id of tag to remove>)
```

I don't understand how I would achieve this functionality with JavaScript.

My thoughts are doing something like:

```
# "class" definition
function Tag() {
  var methods = {
    init : function() { ... }

    append : function(options) {
      var element = <...build DIV element...>;
      $("#tags").append(element);
    }

    remove : function(domid) {
      $(domid).remove();
    }
  }
}

# usage
var tag = Tag.new()
tag.remove("tag_10")
...
```

However, if I do it this way, will I have to create a new `var tag = Tag.new()` each time I want to reference the Tag class (since I'm sending some code back via the server)?

Comment: i'm not sure why you need any sort of "class" or "object" encapsulation here, it seems unnecessary and borderline bad practice in this particular instance. if you don't want each tag to be an "object" mirrored in JS i would suggest just making a couple "static" methods (you know like: function appendTag(...) { ... } ) -ck

Comment: Using objects as JavaScript namespaces is a common practice and not unnecessary as it allow you to avoid cluttering the global namespace with tons of variables and functions. But when doing so there is no need to create a constructor function, an object literal can directly be created (as suggested in Mitch's answer).

Comment: @ckozl I actually would have thought that having random methods tucked into a JS file would be bad practice and that grouping them into "class-like" functionality would have been a better practice. That's generally how it is in most standard languages. However, I'm very new to writing my own JS like this, so I don't know what best practice would be.

Comment: @DanL if you were writing a library or something meant to be portable I would agree with you, but for what your building, which sounds specialized and small, it's perfectly fine to use a simplistic global set of functions as it is perfectly defined in an appropriate scope for what you are doing.  don't listen to "purest zealots" who took their CS101 1st day speech as god's word, "never use a global".  language style rules are just that, rules, there is a time and a place for any rule, this doesn't seem to me to be a circumstance where you need to avoid the global namespace. just my 0.02 -ck

Comment: @ckozl you are correct that in my situation having several stand-alone methods would work fine and would probably be less hassle than extracting them into a class. But I'm working on a personal project for the specific reason of forcing myself to learn how to organize code properly for larger projects. Not sure if my approach is a good one, but I'll try it out and see if it's something I'd want to use in a larger project. You do make an excellent point about doing what makes sense vs following the absolute "rules", though. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to group your functions as a jQuery plugin, returning an object with chainable utility functions:

```
$.fn.tags = function() {
  var tagContainer = this;
  var tags = {
    append : function(options) {
      var element = <...build DIV element...>;
      tagContainer.append(element);
      return tags;
    },
    replace: function () {
      <...do stuffs here...>
      return tags;
    },
    remove : function(domid) {
      $(domid, tagContainer).remove();
      return tags;
    }
  }
  return tags;
}

$('#tags').tags().append({text: 'foo', id: 'bar'}).remove('#tag_10');
```

Comment: I understand that $.fn.tags allows me to call $("...").tags(), but what is the use of the "var tags = {...}" wrapper around the method definitions?  How can you reference $("#tags").tags().append(), wouldn't you need to do $("#tags").tags().tags().append() ? Just trying to understand why it is the way it is.

Comment: $("...").tags() will return the tags object defined in the function ("return tags"). This object has three methods, the helpers functions to manipulate your tags elements. These three methods are defined in a scope where tagContainer is the jQuery object on which the tags() function has been applied to ("var tagContainer = this").

Comment: In $('#tags').tags().append({text: 'foo', id: 'bar'}) there is three function/method calls. First, $('#tags') which return a jQuery object bound to the DOM element matching the #tags selector. Then $('#tags').tags() which returns an object with three methods and no property. And finally $('#tags').tags().append({text: 'foo', id: 'bar'}) which append a new element to DOM element matching the #tags selector and returns the object itself, allowing method chaining.

Answer (score 4):

```
var Tag = {};

Tag.something = function(param) {
/// blah blah blha
};
```

Should work. This will make a `Tag` namespace of sorts.

Comment: +1 This is the functionality I want, but Pierre's answer below provides more of the "class-like" functionality I'm looking for.